# How to fix triple boot (Win7,Ubuntu,Fedora)

Tags: linux, multi-boot

I install Win7 first
then I install Ubuntu in a separate partition it run ok with grub
last i install fedora in a separate partition it run with 2 choice win7 and fedora

I use hiren boot cd to boot with mini linux and run grub 2.0 application on it.
i set up and run i only use Win7 and booot linux error.
I need your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try option 3 on this:

http://bithacker.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-reinstall-fix-grub2-after.html

Keep this page in your bookmarks, becomes in handy!! 
Also CHROOT method is a little bit of a pain, but works the best.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to reinstall fedora THEN ubuntu to have everything setup properly.

Otherwise , you can poke around the grub configuration. Your problem maybe that grub can't find the specified kernel because it is in the wrong specified path.

So checkout /etc. -that is where ALL configuration files are - and edit the grub configuration with a TEXT editor.

Also check /boot - to see where the kernel is .

To access the partition - use your boot a liveCD and mount it. Windows is too self centered to worry about linux.